Universal links and AppleWebKit browser
We are trying to develop an authentication mechanism where in the user clicks on a button to open an authentication app from the browser. We are using the universal link of the app (not maintained by us) to open it. While it works fine from mobile Safari, Chrome etc.., it doesn't work when the browser is AppleWebKit (the one that you use to showcase browser content within an application context).
Do we know if this is a known issue? For reference, we are using a simple window.open(<universal link>, '_blank') to open the application. Also it doesn't work with a custom scheme link as well.
